# How to see the description of a Declared Variable in iOS

Tags: ios

I have a simple question on iOS coding style. Suppose someone is implement the code and he/she not giving any proper naming convention for variable.

I want to see, what is the main purpose ya why he/she use this variable with pressing Alt+mouse pointer on that variable name. But it not showing properly.

My output is :

[image]

My required output will be:

[image]

My question is how can get the **Declaration** & **Description** like above image.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write down where you declare this variable in .h file

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

Write like this:

```
/**
 For getting Current location
 */
CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

Then you can see like your requirement.